# Why it appears that regexp' OR is order sensitive?

Tags: python, regex

```
print(nltk.regexp_tokenize('That U.S.A. poster-print costs $12.40...13.10', r"((?:(?:[A-Z]\.)+)|(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))"))
```

Outputs:

```
"['That', 'U.S.A.', 'poster-print', 'costs', '12', '40', '13', '10']"
```

And (change in the order of the patterns in parentheses):

```
print(nltk.regexp_tokenize('That U.S.A. poster-print costs $12.40...13.10', r"((?:(?:[A-Z]\.)+)|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\w+(?:-\w+)*))"))
```

Outputs:

```
['That', 'U.S.A.', 'poster-print', 'costs', '12.40', '13.10']
```

Why the order in this case matters?

Comment: Because `\w` also matches what `\d` matches.

Comment: Regex just work this way. First match in an or-ed regex wins.